# Group By After LookUp

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have to count how many customers we have "Active" and "Inactive" in our system.
I could just group by `Status` and have it.
The problem is that each customer belongs to an office which might be "Inactive".

So, before knowing my customers' `Status`, I need to match only the "Active" offices.
How can I do that?

Offices:

```
[
  {
    _id: UUID('d0ca792b-6ab3-464c-92ec-241be5551405'),
    Name: 'Office1',
    Status: 'Active'
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('1e49c08b-dfdb-4b29-aa01-63f32086647d'),
    Name: 'Office2',
    Status: 'Inactive'
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('d20d002f-a343-478b-9910-ceb2ee5d9fd3'),
    Name: 'Office3',
    Status: 'Active'
   }
]
```

Customers:

```
[
  {
    _id: UUID('10734c4f-c7c9-4db0-8bc6-2077cb85c242'),
    Status: 0,
    OfficeId: UUID('d0ca792b-6ab3-464c-92ec-241be5551405')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('557fe764-c345-4fd7-94fa-086ce9e95415'),
    Status: 0,
    OfficeId: UUID('d20d002f-a343-478b-9910-ceb2ee5d9fd3')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('b8998295-700b-451e-aff9-8c2a61ee25d3'),
    Status: 0,
    OfficeId: UUID('d0ca792b-6ab3-464c-92ec-241be5551405')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('f90bce6d-a35d-4733-8d53-3085b15412d7'),
    Status: 1,
    OfficeId: UUID('d20d002f-a343-478b-9910-ceb2ee5d9fd3')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('3023ad50-6dde-4c1b-b695-c75a147481e1'),
    Status: 0,
    OfficeId: UUID('d0ca792b-6ab3-464c-92ec-241be5551405')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('74c46c51-6738-4eb8-ba47-a494189db5b4'),
    Status: 1,
    OfficeId: UUID('d20d002f-a343-478b-9910-ceb2ee5d9fd3')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('447542b4-bf34-4a74-8168-c068248ae703'),
    Status: 1,
    OfficeId: UUID('1e49c08b-dfdb-4b29-aa01-63f32086647d')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('aa461e7b-5a40-4e74-91f0-82c8df9c6106'),
    Status: 0,
    OfficeId: UUID('d20d002f-a343-478b-9910-ceb2ee5d9fd3')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('06d224f1-fc7f-4395-934b-41f53bf6439b'),
    Status: 1,
    OfficeId: UUID('1e49c08b-dfdb-4b29-aa01-63f32086647d')
  },
  {
    _id: UUID('6bf2b36d-3470-4d1a-a50e-70b693b02ea5'),
    Status: 0,
    OfficeId: UUID('d20d002f-a343-478b-9910-ceb2ee5d9fd3')
  }
]
```

Comment: Your expected output will be showing the active customer that under the active office right?

Comment: Both Active and Inactive Customers, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main concept implementation:

1. Join both "Customers" and "Offices" collections.
2. Filter the documents with the office's `Status` is "Active".

Solution 1:

```
db.Customers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Offices",
      localField: "OfficeId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "office"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "office.Status": "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "office"
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1nFokncnzdB)

---

Solution 2:

```
db.Customers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Offices",
      localField: "OfficeId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            Status: "Active"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "office"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "office": {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "office"
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sqfBU0CizIY)

Comment: If my Customers collection is too big, it would consume less resources if I started the aggregation in the Offices collections and then lookup only the related documents from Customers?


If so, how would it be?

Comment: Probably this should be what you need. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qi6O-899IoG)